# Nothing under Tomcat 9.0 folder

Tags: tomcat9

I can't see any files under my Tomcat folder (C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation). This is the only Tomcat folder I have. Strangely, it is working fine, I can see that localhost:8080 shows that Tomcat was properly installed and it is running.

Answer (score 0):

[Got apache tomcat error that access denied on this file localhost_access_log.2014-08-30.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25579459/got-apache-tomcat-error-that-access-denied-on-this-file-localhost-access-log-201) -> this is a solution. After I've given the rights i can see all necessary files inside a folder.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

try this command it should shows the tomcat folder

```
jps -lv
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem before. You have to first right click on the folder (C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation) --> Properties --> unselect Read Only in Attributes --> Click on Apply (also click Continue if there is a prompt). Then you'll see all the files under the Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0 folder.

Now you can restart Eclipse and configure the Tomcat server again.